# Ошибка с выводом элементов canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, for

Нужно разместить несколько элементов на холсте.
Делаю через цикл, всё должно работать по-моему, но ничего на холсте не отображается.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2D');


 var tileW = 40, tileH = 40;
 var mapW = 10, mapH = 10;

 for (var x = 0; x < mapW; x++) 
        {
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 ctx.fillRect (x * tileW, 0, tileW, tileH);  
        }                                
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправьте `var ctx = canvas.getContext('2D')` на `var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')`
Этот метод чувствителен к регистру.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Holter Всегда пожалуйста :)